# how to convert dataframe to multi level dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have list and dataframe

```
list1 = ['one', 'two', 'three']
list2 = ['a', 'b']
```

df is

```
    A     B     C    D
0   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
1   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
```

then how to convert into multilevel indexing dataframe which as follows

```
        A             B       C   D
   one two three    a    b
0  NaN NaN NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
1  NaN NaN NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
```

or

```
        A             B      
   one two three    a    b     C   D
0  NaN NaN NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
1  NaN NaN NaN     NaN  NaN   NaN NaN
```

Comment: What label do you want for the second level under `C` and `D`? Empty strings?

Comment: Welcome to SO, What values  do you expect in A-> one, A->two, etc., you have only 4 columns after applying multi dimensional column count increase to more than 4. So please provide a valid sample so that you will get solution easily

Comment: for now C and D are empty, later if required i will add

Comment: How do you intend to broadcast data? Do you just want to create a dataframe of `NaN` values with a specified index length?

Comment: I have data for every column in list, like A-one columns has data in list [x,y,z,a,b,c]

Comment: Let me put it more simply: your desired output has more columns than your input dataframe. How do you want to fill your extra columns?

Comment: I have values for all A_one, A_two, A_three, B_a, B_b,  C, D  I need the desired dataframe output